# How to create a global configuration page for my custom field type?

Tags: add-on, module, plugin, fieldtype

I have created a custom field type which integrates with a web service. I need to create a simple interface which allows the User ID and API key to be configured globally.

Will I need to create a module for this?

A simple example would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a configuration page for your fieldtype by including a `display_global_settings()` and a `save_global_settings()` which display and save the settings respectively.

When your fieldtype class is instantiated your current settings are passed to a public `settings` property. You access your current settings within the `display_global_settings()` method with `$this->settings['setting_name']`. To display the settings page, return a string containing the HTML. You do not need to include a form tag or submit button in the returned HTML, these will be added for you.

To save the settings, you will create a `save_global_settings()` method. This method should retrieve the values using the `$this->EE->input->post()` method. You can manipulate the settings however you need, or simply place them all into a single array. The value you return from this method will be saved to the database and set to `$this->settings` next time the class is instantiated.

You can set the default settings value by returning it from the `install()` method.

You can find some examples under the [global setting section of the fieldtype developer docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html#global-settings).

Comment: Fantastic, this worked perfectly :)